# conda env name breaks oh-my-zsh formatting

Tags: shell, anaconda, conda, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed oh-my-zsh and copied all my user-defined variables and other tid-bits(conda, SDKMAN) to from .bashrc to .zshrc.
I have the `Cascadia Code Mono PL` font installed on Windows, and Windows Terminal can access it.
oh-my-zsh is configured to use the [`fino`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#fino) theme

However, after installing oh-my-zsh the `(base)` that appears as the conda env name moves the CLI line around and breaks it.

Problem Screenshot:
[image: Problem Screenshot]

What I've added to the end of my `~/.zshrc` file.

```
# User Defined Variables

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/v4g4x/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/v4g4x/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/v4g4x/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/v4g4x/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# User-defined path of a Default Browser for Juptyer
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

# User-defined path for IntelliJ IDEA
export IDEA='/home/v4g4x/idea'
export PATH=$PATH:$IDEA/bin/

# User-defined Path for MPJ Express
export MPJ_HOME='/home/v4g4x/mpj'
export PATH=$PATH:$MPJ_HOME/bin/

# Custom Beginning Folder Location for terminal
cd ~/

# xclip Alias
alias "c=xclip -selection clipboard"
alias "v=xclip -selection clipboard -o"


#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/home/v4g4x/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/home/v4g4x/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/v4g4x/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

I am new to zsh and modding terminals, any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh) themes aren't written to accommodate the conda env name.
I moved to [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) and used that theme.
It handles the conda env name beautifully and is quite customizable.